# Ordered list in two columns with some long entries

Tags: css

I'm working on an ordered list with a series of *li* tags with entries of varying length. I want to get them into two columns (without using column count for now). What I want to achieve is this:

```
Item 1              Item 2
Item 3 so           Item 4
long it overflows  
Item 5              Item 6
Item 7 also too     Item 8
long but isn't such
a problem on right
```

but this is what I get at best.

```
Item 1             Item 2
Item 3 so          Item 4
long it overflows  Item 5
Item 6             Item 7 also too long but
                   isn't such a problem on right
Item 7             Item 8
```

Whatever I try, floats, display:inline, etc., at best I get my first example. Can anyone think of a clean way of doing this in CSS?

EDIT: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c0rLqqbw/1

Comment: Show us the HTML you used to create the columns.

Comment: please provide some code to look into. thanks

Comment: So, you want to achieve your first example, and at best you get your first example?

Comment: I've put together a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c0rLqqbw/1/ with a realistic example of wording to show how it gets confusing (the colours are wrong but this is what happens on my website). You'll see that odd/even swaps when one of the colours is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is little bit confusing, but if do you mean to one order list splited to 2 cloumns with css only then you can use:

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>item 1</li> 
    <li>item 2</li> 
    <li>item 3 - so Item 4 long it overflows so Item 4 long it overflows</li> 
    <li>item 4</li> 
    <li>item 5</li> 
    <li>item 6</li> 
    <li>item 7 - also too long but isn't such
a problem on right</li> 
    <li>item 8</li>
<ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

li:nth-child(odd)
{
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

li:nth-child(even)
{
    float: right;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rm8Ldyyj/

Comment: Just looked at this and I think it works! I'll mark it as correct as soon as I've fully tested it!

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'd completely forgotten about clearing floats. As it happens, I won't float right as I also have lists in three columns. Floating everything left is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use columns at all. Try:

```
.myContainer li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flexbox, however not much browser support.

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3 So long it overflows</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
   <li>Item 7 also too long but isn't such a problem on right</li>
   <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   width: 200px;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}

li {
   flex: 1 1 50%;
}
```

Comment: This actually works but I'm nervous about the support for flex in older browsers and how it degrades.